# Initialize property which needs Add method - C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a control which I can add some other controls in it.
I need to add those controls in object initialization but it will give me an error that the Controls property is an `indexer` and it is `read-only`. so I should add in it in another line using the `Add` method. Is there any way to do such thing in object initialization?

```
pgvSections.Pages.Add(new PageView() { Name = sectionName, /* Controls = DOES NOT ALLOWED */  });
pgvSections.Pages.Last().Controls.Add(someControl);
```

Comment: Please update your tags - is it WebForms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on GitHub linked by PetSerAl (kudos to him for pointing out my mistake), something like `Controls = { new Control(), new Control(), ... }` is allowed, because it automatically gets converted to a series of `Controls.Add()`.

Comment: *There is no way to `Add` elements to a collection in an object initializer* Can you provide any reference to support your claim? It seems work fine for me: https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgBgARwIwG4CwAoRLUAsWuAzPgGwoBM+A7EgN45IsplqVwFICyAhgEsoACgCUjZqykBhJAGMkAXiRQApgHckshkgAyAgM7AljJKgA0SKpbIBfJLeJSpaAJzC0CAHQApAPZCwgBEliHyXvpGoqJOrLY48aTUWhLYLmSRwAA8QsAAfHqGxjoA5qrA6A4mapqZOVD5YsSJQA===

Comment: That's suprising. In your example, that syntax appears to be automatically converted to `List.AddRange(new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 })`. I can't find any documentation regarding that, but nevertheless, it works, so I suppose nothing prevents the OP from doing something like `Controls = { new Control(), new Control(), ... }`. Thank you for sharing that, @PetSerAl.

Comment: You can find specification [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#object-initializers).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. C# never stops to amaze me.